# I get this error wit R Studio: ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character Î² (U+03B2) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: beamer, rmarkdown

My code in RStudio is the next one:

````
 ---
 title: "QUESTION 8 (a)"
 author: "Ana Márquez"
 date: "17/2/2023"
 output: 
        beamer_presentation:
        theme: "Malmoe"
        colortheme: "crane"
        toc: true
        slide_level: 2
  ---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tinytex)
library(revealjs)
library(ISLR)
```


# Enunciado

Utilice la función lm() para realizar una regresión lineal simple con "mpg" como respuesta y "horsepower" como predictor. Utilice la función summary() para imprimir los resultados. Comente el resultado. Por ejemplo:



# Apartado i)

¿Existe una relación entre el predictor y la respuesta?


```{r}
data(Auto)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ horsepower, data = Auto)
```



```{r}
summary(fit)
```


Podemos responder a esta pregunta probando la hipótesis $H_0:\beta=0$  $∀_i$. El p valor correspondiente al estadístico F es $7,03198910^{-81}$, lo que indica una clara evidencia de relación entre “mpg” y “horsepower”.
````

When I try to knit to a pdf, the error I get is:

```
output file: q8--a.knit.md
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character Î² (U+03B2)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.
Error: LaTeX failed to compile q8--a.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See q8--a.log for more info.
Ejecución interrumpida
```

Comment: @Ana Please don't remove the code indention. Otherwise your source code isn't show as a code block!

Comment: STOP removing the code indentation. Otherwise the ` ` `  in your code aren't shown and all the formatting is messed up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main problems:

- If you typeset math content like `H_0` it needs to be in math mode. Wrap it e.g. in `$...$` to switch to math mode.
- if you want to use special characters like `β` you should either switch to an unicode aware engine like `lualatex` or use the proper latex macro `\beta` instead of these symbols.

---

````
---
title: "QUESTION 8 (a)"
author: "Ana"
date: "17/2/2023"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Malmoe"
    colortheme: "crane"
    toc: true
    slide_level: 2
    latex_engine: lualatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tinytex)
library(revealjs)
library(ISLR)
```


# Enunciado

Utilice la función lm() para realizar una regresión lineal simple con "mpg" como respuesta y "horsepower" como predictor. Utilice la función summary() para imprimir los resultados. Comente el resultado. Por ejemplo:



# Apartado i)

¿Existe una relación entre el predictor y la respuesta?


```{r}
data(Auto)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ horsepower, data = Auto)
summary(fit)
```


Podemos responder a esta pregunta probando la hipótesis $H_0:βi=0 ∀_i$. El p valor correspondiente al estadístico F es $7,03198910^{-81}$, lo que indica una clara evidencia de relación entre “mpg” y “horsepower”.
````

Comment: I dit it and the error is still appearing.

Comment: @Ana Did you try the exact same code as in my question or with your own document?

Comment: Now it works! Thank you so much, it was adding lualatex and now it´s all ok.

Comment: One more question, If I want the part of summary in another slide, how can I do this?

Comment: @Ana If you have a new question, you should use the "Ask question" button at the top right